# Sharepoint ribbon greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I was trying to exclude the "Export to Spreadsheet" from survey for users and after I got into this.

[image]

[image]

When i pressed one of the issues in Central Admin, I got this:

---

I wanted to make a survey in SharePoint 2013 but I didn't want users to see the results so I removed the following code:

```
<SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplaterunat="server" FeatureScope="Site"
            Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
            GroupId="ActionsMenuForSurvey"
            UseShortId="true"
            ...
            runat="server">
```

from the file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates` and was ok. After 
server restart I noticed that even if I have admin rights I can't upload documents, create new folders, use library setting etc. So I restorede it back and saved it but things are the same. I still have admin rights.

Comment: I cant add pictures......so New Document,Upload Document from FIles menu and Library settings from library are greyed out. Also survey application doesnt have buttons at all.

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete, I am unable to understand it. Please can you elaborate or improve the description. So that you can get more attention on it.

Comment: thanks...i wanted to make a survey in SharePoint 2013, but, didnt want users to see results so i cut the following <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate ID="ExportToSpreadsheet"
Text="<%$Resources:wss,ToolBarMenuItemExportToSpreadsheet%>"    Description<%$Resources:wss,ToolBarMenuItemExportToSpreadsheetDescription%>"PermissionsString="UseClientIntegration"PermissionContext="CurrentList"MenuGroupId="800"Sequence="100"ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/MenuSpreadsheet.gif?rev=23"UseShortId="true" runat="server"/>
from

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates and was ok. After server restart I noticed that even if i have admin rights i cant upload document, create new folder, use library setting etc. So i copy it back and saved it but things are the same.

Comment: You can update your question with these details. It will helpful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your page is edited and in webpart properties of survey, ToolBar type is set to "No Toolbar" instead of "Full ToolBar" Once Full toolbar is enabled, you should see action option from where you can export data to excel.

Comment: Buttons greyed out doesnt appear only to survey but in all applications and all sites. I think is something with C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates. can i find it somewhere and restore it?

Comment: is that a complete page screenshot? It looks customised. Can you go to one of the document library , select one of the file and check behavior in ribbon section? i know, its not very much helping, just trying to troubleshoot.  For defaulttemplate file part, do you see file modified time..if its edited manually?

Comment: Done this...nothing.....i also have admin rights.

Comment: There is something wrong in general cause i cant see specific buttons on every site. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing IIRESET or server restart as a last option? Also FYI, Modifying system files from server is not supported/recommended and there is chance that they will be overwritten during upgrade.

Comment: i did iisreset and system restart but is the same. Can i find and restore the default templates in internet?

Comment: I doubt that, also you need to mention your current sharepoint version details in question, SO that in case anyone here has same version , can help you with this file. You can find version number at http//centraladminURL/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx

Comment: Configuration database version:15.0.4719.1000 sharepoint 2013 build 4719 revision 1000

Comment: still no solution